# User input as argument in stack

Tags: c++, stack

What I'm trying to do is push user input onto stack using functions, since I have a switch-case menu and each case has it's own function(print stack, add onto stack..) Printing the stack works, user input works as well, but it seems that nothing is being added to the stack.
I'll show you the things I've tried so far:

```
void addStack(stack <int> myStack, int number){
    myStack.push(number);
}
```

Main function:

```
    int nm;
    stack <int> st;

    do{
        menu();
        cin >> selection;
        switch(selection){
            case 2:
                cin >> nm;
                addStack(st,nm);
                break;
            case 3:
                printStack(st);
                break;
```

The thing i initially tried was putting everything into the function itself:

```
void addStack(stack <int> myStack){
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    myStack.push(number);
}
```

But I got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such prototypes:

```
void addStack(stack<int> myStack)
```

The changes are made locally, and as soon as the function reaches the end, everything is discarded. For this reason, you may want to use a reference-to operator – so that you can change the *actual* value (which is passed as the parameter).

You can do that like this:

```
void addStack(stack<int>& myStack)
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, it actually worked:) Do you mind explaining that a bit more, since I'm not too sure I understand it

Comment: You can pass an argument using two methods, namely pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. When you use an ampersand operator, it would mean that anything changes you would make are applied in the original instance. On the other hand, it will indicate that you only want to make changes locally (to the scope of the function only).

Comment: Oh, so basically by adding that operator, I'm making it "passable" throughout the whole program, as the other answer suggests, if I made my stack st; global, it would work the same?

Comment: @ekaeo Yes, but beware of altering the scope of any variable to global – always try to keep the variables with the least visibility as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `st` to `addStack()` via callByValue , that means the method `addSTack()` has it's own copy of stack and whatever change you make inside that method doesn't reflect back in the `main()` method .

Solution:

1. Make the `stack <int> st` global , that is declare it outside any method and  then you won't need to pass it to each and every method
2. Pass `st` via call by reference , this will make the changes made in `addStack()` method reflect back in the calling method (.i.e. main())

Comment: Thanks man, making the stack global made it easier for me to understand